# Error in ASP.NET Core MVC and Web API project

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC and also Web API project.

This error occurs when I try to send project information to the API (of course API works fine and I do not think there is a problem):

> UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read a "TokenModel" object of "text / plain" media content.

My code is:

```
public class TokenModel
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

and in `AuthController` I have:

```
var _Client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyApiClient");

var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = _Client.PostAsync("/Api/Authentication", content).Result;
        
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var token = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>().Result;
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
var token = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>().Result;
```

`HomeController`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var token = User.FindFirst("AccessToken").Value;
    return View(_user.GetAllUsers(token));
}
```

`UserRepository`:

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetAllUsers(string token)
{
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    var res = _client.GetStringAsync(UrlMyApi).Result;

    List<UserViewModel> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserViewModel>>(res);
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API is returning content-type of `text/plain` and none of the default media type formatters(`MediaTypeFormatter`) which `ReadAsAsync<string>()` will try to use support parsing it as is. They work with JSON/XML. You can go a couple of ways but maybe the easiest is to read the content as string and deserialize it after:

```
var tokenJSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(tokenJSON);
```

Also, as you're using the **Async** methods, you should be returning `Task` from your actions and `await` the result instead of using `.Result` as you're just creating overhead currently.

```
var tokenJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(tokenJSON);
```